# CSS content-visibility property does not work on Site Footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to optimize the website performance using the new **content-visibility** property. I have applied the `content-visibility: auto` style to my website footer. I can confirm that the footer is not visible on the view port on initial load of the website. My understanding was that the footer will not be rendered since it is not in the view-port. But it keeps getting rendered completely. The rendering time also increases when I check the performance metrics from chrome developer tools.

When I explicitly apply the following style `content-visibility: hidden` I see that the footer is not visible. My understanding of the property was that when I set the property to auto and the element is not visible under the viewport, it is treated as hidden, and when it comes into the viewport, it is treated as visible again.

Any ideas on what I might be missing? any leads on this would be really helpful. Thanks.